# How to put an array of bytes ( a PDF file ) into my clipboard

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf, byte, clipboard

I'm looking for a solution as I couldn't do it from the back end .NET Web API.

I tried using the WinForms Clipboard but I wasn't able to do it.

I'm trying to put the array of bytes I received from the server-side into my clipboard to use later with any paste operation such as (Ctrl+V).

But I don't know how could I reach that?

Comment: i think you can only put strings into clipboard, so you would have to convert it to json or csv before

Comment: So it is not possible to put any object into the clipboard, even from the server-side ?
I want to add the pdf to the clipboard and the user would paste it in any file explorer or in the browser or anywhere he wants.
I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Oh i didn't see you were making a WinForms app. Maybe it is possible, thats not my area though

Comment: There is an easy way and a hard way. The easy way is, save the received byte array in a temporary pdf file and place it in the Clipboard with [Clipboard.SetFileDropList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setfiledroplist?view=net-5.0). The hard way is using virtual files. Do a search for `FileGroupDescriptor`, there are many posts regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the data of a file in the clipboard, just a reference to a file on the filesystem. This is why you cant paste a file after you have deleted or moved it.

To do this programmatically, see the [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard) class. More specifically, the [SetFileDropList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setfiledroplist?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Clipboard_SetFileDropList_System_Collections_Specialized_StringCollection_) method. Just pass it a StringCollection with the paths of files you want "copied" into the clipboard.

Comment: Can I do that in a .NET project?

Comment: Of course, just make sure you use [System.Windows.Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0) instead of the Winforms one. I misread your question and thought you were writing a WinForms app.